# Is this ideal maximal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have a problem set in which a question in its premise assumes that $<7,\sqrt{10}>$ the principal ideal generated by 7 and $\sqrt{10}$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]=\{a+b\sqrt{10}:a,b$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}\} $.

But I showed that $<7,\sqrt{10}>$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$. So it can't be maximal, since in the definition a maximal ideal must be a proper ideal.

My work: I showed that $<7,\sqrt{10}> = \{7a+10b+c\sqrt{10} : a,b, c\in \mathbb{Z} \} = \{s+t\sqrt{10} : t, s  \in \mathbb{Z}\}=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}].$

I used the fact that 7 and 10 are relatively prime, so we can write any integer $n$ as a combination of them.
Is my work false? And if it is in fact a maximal ideal, how I can show that?

Edit: in the question it asks me to show that $<7,\sqrt{10}>$ is maximal by considering the quotient ring.

Comment: Principal ideal means it is generated by one element, which is not true in the case of the ideal $(7,\sqrt{10})$

Comment: You are right. We have $3\cdot 7-(2\sqrt{10})\sqrt{10}=1\in \langle 7,\sqrt{10}\rangle$, so $\langle 7,\sqrt{10}\rangle$ is the whole ring and is not maximal.

Comment: It is the ideal generated by $7$ and $\sqrt{10}$. In this case, as it is the whole ring, then it is indeed principal, but this is just a particular case. The ideal generated by $x$ and $y$ in $K[x,y]$ is maximal for any field $K$, but it is far from being principal. Just observe $1\notin (x,y)$

Answer (score 1):

Presumably a typo in the question: the ideal $\langle 7,\sqrt{10}\rangle$ is actually principal, but for the simple reason that it equals $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$, so it's definitely not maximal.

The question is probably about the principal ideal $\langle 7+\sqrt{10}\rangle$, which is a different beast.

Consider the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X]\to\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$ that maps $X$ to $\sqrt{10}$; its kernel is generated by the polynomial $X^2-14X-39$ and is so contained in the ideal generated by $X$ and $3$. So the idea might be to show that $3+\langle7+\sqrt{10}\rangle$ is not invertible in the quotient ring.

From $3(x+y\sqrt{10})=1+(u+v\sqrt{10})(7+\sqrt{10})$ we obtain
$$
3x=1+7u+10v,\qquad 3y=u+7v
$$
Work modulo $3$ and find a contradiction.